# Checking heap being used by a running process on Solaris 10

Tags: c, heap-memory, solaris, solaris-10

How can I check heap being used by a running process on Solaris 10?
pmap is providing info, but I would like to see the heap usage, do I have to do like this?

```
pmap | grep [heap]
```

If we would like to know programmatically from within the program, we may use the following command:

```
struct mallinfo mallinfo(void);
```

The mallinfo() function returns a copy of a structure containing information about memory allocations performed by malloc and related functions.  This structure is defined as follows:

```
       struct mallinfo {
           int arena;     /* Non-mmapped space allocated (bytes) */
           int ordblks;   /* Number of free chunks */
           int smblks;    /* Number of free fastbin blocks */
           int hblks;     /* Number of mmapped regions */
           int hblkhd;    /* Space allocated in mmapped regions (bytes) */
           int usmblks;   /* Maximum total allocated space (bytes) */
           int fsmblks;   /* Space in freed fastbin blocks (bytes) */
           int uordblks;  /* Total allocated space (bytes) */
           int fordblks;  /* Total free space (bytes) */
           int keepcost;  /* Top-most, releasable space (bytes) */
       };
```

Will this be helpful to know how much memory we have already allocated (total memory allocated - total memory deallocated as the net memory allocated)?

Comment: If you can run `dtrace`, you might be interested in [Memory growth flame graphs](http://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/memoryflamegraphs.html)

Answer (score 1):

Investigating the functions available from `<procfs.h>` is probably
your best bet.